# not to let user to enter value in combobox other than databound list

Tags: c#, combobox

i have a combobox in the form which is bounded with database .

i am trying to solve two issues .

1. not to let user to enter the values that are not in data list .
2. not to run code until the full value is entered .

for eg. when i enter the first letter of any value and press enter ,code is running with the values that first matched the entered word . like for 'd' code is running with  no 'd001'

requirement is that , no execution until the user enter or select the full value .

thanks in advance and sorry for any English  related error .

Comment: Why don't you just populate your combobox with the database values from that column ? How many entries are you expecting ?

Answer (score 0):

Try below from code

```
comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
```

You can also set the `DropDownStyle` to `DropDownList` from Properties window of the combobox.